# Encountering an error while trying to update the kernel

Tags: 18.04, kernel, dpkg, dependencies

I am trying to update the kernel from 5.4 to 5.14 on Ubuntu 18.04, but I am seeing this dpkg error. Can someone please help with this?

Files under Downloads directory:

```
linux-headers-5.14.6-051406_5.14.6-051406.202109181232_all.deb
linux-headers-5.14.6-051406-generic_5.14.6-051406.202109181232_amd64.deb
linux-image-unsigned-5.14.6-051406-generic_5.14.6-051406.202109181232_amd64.deb
linux-modules-5.14.6-051406-generic_5.14.6-051406.202109181232_amd64.deb
```

Terminal:

```
computer@computer:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
(Reading database ... 152907 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-5.14.6-051406_5.14.6-051406.202109181232_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.14.6-051406 (5.14.6-051406.202109181232) over (5.14.6-051406.202109181232) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-5.14.6-051406-generic.
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-5.14.6-051406-generic_5.14.6-051406.202109181232_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.14.6-051406-generic (5.14.6-051406.202109181232) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-image-unsigned-5.14.6-051406-generic_5.14.6-051406.202109181232_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-unsigned-5.14.6-051406-generic (5.14.6-051406.202109181232) over (5.14.6-051406.202109181232) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-modules-5.14.6-051406-generic_5.14.6-051406.202109181232_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-5.14.6-051406-generic (5.14.6-051406.202109181232) over (5.14.6-051406.202109181232) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.14.6-051406 (5.14.6-051406.202109181232) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-5.14.6-051406-generic:
 linux-headers-5.14.6-051406-generic depends on libc6 (>= 2.34); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.27-3ubuntu1.4.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-5.14.6-051406-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-modules-5.14.6-051406-generic (5.14.6-051406.202109181232) ...
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-5.14.6-051406-generic (5.14.6-051406.202109181232) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-5.14.6-051406-generic (5.14.6-051406.202109181232) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.14.6-051406-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p6
I: (UUID=80f48344-6855-4294-a155-f314f4771cbc)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.14.6-051406-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.14.6-051406-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-84-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-84-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-5.14.6-051406-generic
```

Comment: You can perhaps install kernel 5.14 onto Ubuntu 18.04. However you cannot do so using a deb package. The dependencies don't match and there's no way around that using debs. Kernel 5.11 has been tested with 18.04, for that use [HWE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), which DOES use debs.

Comment: +1, exept kernel 5.4 is the last one available for 18.04. You have to migrate to 20.04, which has 5.11 now, and will get either 5.13 or 5.14 sometime next year.

Comment: see the related [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1926938), which contains workarounds.